# SyntaxError when attempting to run .js script in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

I expect this is a relatively simple question, but I've been digging around and haven't been able to find a solution as of yet.  I am learning MongoDB/NoSQL recently and have a .js file that I'm attempting to run via command line, ex:

```
mongo < myscript.js
```

But unfortunately, I am receiving syntax errors (uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :) instead of successful output in the terminal.  I am doing some basic .insert(), .update(), and then subsequent .find() and .aggregate() to display that data. Is there some syntax or formatting that I need to adjust when using my code as a script?  Running the code in segments inside of the Mongo Shell yields positive results everything runs successfully. Here is my .js code:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('PurpleBoxDVD');
db.RentalCollection.insertMany(
[
    {
        "_id": "0000001", 
        "userID": "PB0000001", 
        "userFirstName" : "Drew", 
        "userLastName": "Weidman", 
        "userPhoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "userType": "A", 
        "customerType": "P", 
        "banStatus": "N", 
        "password": "SQLRules", 
        "question": 
        [
            {
            "Question1": "What was the name of your first pet?",
            "Answer1": "Tim"
            },
            {
            "Question2": "What elementary school did you attend?",
            "Answer2": "Desert Hills"
            }
        ],
        "rentalDate": "Jun 28 2020", 
        "returnDate": "null", 
        "dueDate": "Jul 01 2020", 
        "copyNumber": "3", 
        "movieType": "B", 
        "title": "True Grit", 
        "actor":
        [
            {
            "actor1FirstName": "John",
            "actor1LastName": "Wayne"
            },
            {
            "actor2FirstName": "Glen",
            "actor2LastName": "Campbell"
            }
        ],
        "directorFirstName": "Henry",
        "directorLastName": "Hathaway",
        "genre": ["Adventure","Drama","Western"], 
        "keyword": ["Rooster Cogburn","US Marshal","Oscar Award Winner"]    
    },
    
    {
        "_id": "0000002", 
        "userID": "PB0000002", 
        "userFirstName" : "Kolten", 
        "userLastName": "Nay", 
        "userPhoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "userType": "A", 
        "customerType": "P", 
        "banStatus": "N", 
        "password": "SQLRules", 
        "question": 
        [
            {
            "Question1": "Who is the best professor in the CS Department?",
            "Answer1": "Cody Squadroni"
            },
            {
            "Question2": "What was the name of your first pet?",
            "Answer2": "Kirby"
            }
        ],
        "rentalDate": "Jun 28 2020", 
        "returnDate": "null", 
        "dueDate": "Jul 01 2020", 
        "copyNumber": "1", 
        "movieType": "D", 
        "title": "The Sons of Katie Elder", 
        "actor":
        [
            {
            "actor1FirstName": "John",
            "actor1LastName": "Wayne"
            },
            {
            "actor2FirstName": "Dean",
            "actor2LastName": "Martin"
            }
        ],
        "directorFirstName": "Henry",
        "directorLastName": "Hathaway",
        "genre": ["Western"], 
        "keyword": ["Gun Fighter","Family"] 
    },
    {
        "_id": "0000003", 
        "userID": "PB0000002", 
        "userFirstName" : "Kolten", 
        "userLastName": "Nay", 
        "userPhoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "userType": "A", 
        "customerType": "P", 
        "banStatus": "N", 
        "password": "SQLRules", 
        "question": 
        [
            {
            "Question1": "Who is the best professor in the CS Department?",
            "Answer1": "Cody Squadroni"
            },
            {
            "Question2": "What was the name of your first pet?",
            "Answer2": "Kirby"
            }
        ],
        "rentalDate": "Jun 28 2020", 
        "returnDate": "null", 
        "dueDate": "Jul 01 2020", 
        "copyNumber": "1", 
        "movieType": "D", 
        "title": "The Avengers", 
        "actor":
        [
            {
            "actor1FirstName": "Robert",
            "actor1LastName": "Downey Jr"
            },
            {
            "actor2FirstName": "Chris",
            "actor2LastName": "Evans"
            }
        ],
        "directorFirstName": "Joss",
        "directorLastName": "Whedon",
        "genre": ["Adventure","Action","Sci-Fi"], 
        "keyword": ["Captain America","Iron Man","Thor"]    
    },
    {
        "_id": "0000004", 
        "userID": "PB0000002", 
        "userFirstName" : "Kolten", 
        "userLastName": "Nay", 
        "userPhoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "userType": "A", 
        "customerType": "P", 
        "banStatus": "N", 
        "password": "SQLRules", 
        "question": 
        [
            {
            "Question1": "Who is the best professor in the CS Department?",
            "Answer1": "Cody Squadroni"
            },
            {
            "Question2": "What was the name of your first pet?",
            "Answer2": "Kirby"
            }
        ],
        "rentalDate": "Jun 28 2020", 
        "returnDate": "null", 
        "dueDate": "Jul 01 2020", 
        "copyNumber": "1", 
        "movieType": "D", 
        "title": "Greatest Showman", 
        "actor":
        [
            {
            "actor1FirstName": "Hugh",
            "actor1LastName": "Jackman"
            },
            {
            "actor2FirstName": "Michelle",
            "actor2LastName": "Williams"
            }
        ],
        "directorFirstName": "Michael",
        "directorLastName": "Gracey",
        "genre": ["Drama","Biography","Musical"], 
        "keyword": ["Circus","Barnum","Singing","Million Dreams"]   
    },
    {
        "_id": "0000005", 
        "userID": "PB0000002", 
        "userFirstName" : "Kolten", 
        "userLastName": "Nay", 
        "userPhoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "userType": "A", 
        "customerType": "P", 
        "banStatus": "N", 
        "password": "SQLRules", 
        "question": 
        [
            {
            "Question1": "Who is the best professor in the CS Department?",
            "Answer1": "Cody Squadroni"
            },
            {
            "Question2": "What was the name of your first pet?",
            "Answer2": "Kirby"
            }
        ],
        "rentalDate": "Jun 28 2020", 
        "returnDate": "null", 
        "dueDate": "Jul 01 2020", 
        "copyNumber": "1", 
        "movieType": "D", 
        "title": "Star Wars: Episode IV - New Hope", 
        "actor":
        [
            {
            "actor1FirstName": "Mark",
            "actor1LastName": "Hamill"
            },
            {
            "actor2FirstName": "Carrie",
            "actor2LastName": "Fisher"
            }
        ],
        "directorFirstName": "George",
        "directorLastName": "Lucas",
        "genre": ["Fantasy","Adventure","Action"], 
        "keyword": ["Jedi Knight","Darth Vader","Yoda"]
    },
    {
        "_id": "0000006", 
        "userID": "PB0000021", 
        "userFirstName" : "Spencer", 
        "userLastName": "Hilton", 
        "userPhoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "userPhoneNumber2": "9999999999",
        "userType": "N", 
        "customerType": "P", 
        "banStatus": "N", 
        "password": "CSRocks!", 
        "question": 
        [
            {
            "Question1": "What was your first phone number?",
            "Answer1": "9999999999"
            },
            {
            "Question2": "What is your mothers maiden name?",
            "Answer2": "Johnson"
            }
        ],
        "rentalDate": "Jun 28 2020", 
        "returnDate": "null", 
        "dueDate": "Jul 01 2020", 
        "copyNumber": "3", 
        "movieType": "B", 
        "title": "Deadpool", 
        "actor":
        [
            {
            "actor1FirstName": "Ryan",
            "actor1LastName": "Reynolds"
            },
            {
            "actor2FirstName": "Morena",
            "actor2LastName": "Baccarin"
            }
        ],
        "directorFirstName": "Tim",
        "directorLastName": "Miller",
        "genre": ["Adventure","Action","Comedy"], 
        "keyword": ["Mercinary","Morbid","Healing Power"]
    },
    {
        "_id": "0000007", 
        "userID": "PB0000027", 
        "userFirstName" : "Josh", 
        "userLastName": "Jensen", 
        "userPhoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "userPhoneNumber2": "9999999999",
        "userType": "N", 
        "customerType": "S", 
        "banStatus": "N", 
        "password": "AndroidIsKing", 
        "question": 
        [
            {
            "Question1": "Who is the best professor in the CS Department?",
            "Answer1": "Josh Jensen"
            },
            {
            "Question2": "What was your first phone number?",
            "Answer2": "8016429755"
            }
        ],
        "rentalDate": "Jun 28 2020", 
        "returnDate": "null", 
        "dueDate": "Jul 01 2020", 
        "copyNumber": "1", 
        "movieType": "D", 
        "title": "X-Men", 
        "actor":
        [
            {
            "actor1FirstName": "Hugh",
            "actor1LastName": "Jackman"
            },
            {
            "actor2FirstName": "Patrick",
            "actor2LastName": "Stewart"
            }
        ],
        "directorFirstName": "Bryan",
        "directorLastName": "Singer",
        "genre": ["Adventure","Action","Sci-Fi"], 
        "keyword": ["Wolverine","Mutants"]
    },

    {
        "_id": "0000008", 
        "userID": "PB0000101", 
        "userFirstName" : "Waldo", 
        "userLastName": "Wildcat", 
        "userPhoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "userPhoneNumber2": "9999999999",
        "userType": "N", 
        "customerType": "S", 
        "banStatus": "N", 
        "password": "GoWildcats!", 
        "question": 
        [
            {
            "Question1": "What was the name of your first pet?",
            "Answer1": "Thunderbird"
            },
            {
            "Question2": "What elementary school did you attend?",
            "Answer2": "Bonneville"
            }
        ],
        "rentalDate": "Jun 28 2020", 
        "returnDate": "null", 
        "dueDate": "Jul 01 2020", 
        "copyNumber": "4",  
        "movieType": "B", 
        "title": "The Avengers", 
        "actor":
        [
            {
            "actor1FirstName": "Robert",
            "actor1LastName": "Downey Jr"
            },
            {
            "actor2FirstName": "Chris",
            "actor2LastName": "Evans"
            }
        ],
        "directorFirstName": "Joss",
        "directorLastName": "Whedon",
        "genre": ["Adventure","Action","Sci-Fi"], 
        "keyword": ["Captain America","Iron Man","Thor"]
    },
    {
        "_id": "0000009", 
        "userID": "PB0000101", 
        "userFirstName" : "Waldo", 
        "userLastName": "Wildcat", 
        "userPhoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "userPhoneNumber2": "9999999999",
        "userType": "N", 
        "customerType": "S", 
        "banStatus": "N", 
        "password": "GoWildcats!", 
        "question": 
        [
            {
            "Question1": "What was the name of your first pet?",
            "Answer1": "Thunderbird"
            },
            {
            "Question2": "What elementary school did you attend?",
            "Answer2": "Bonneville"
            }
        ],
        "rentalDate": "Jun 28 2020", 
        "returnDate": "null", 
        "dueDate": "Jul 01 2020", 
        "copyNumber": "3",  
        "movieType": "B", 
        "title": "Incredibles 2", 
        "actor":
        [
            {
            "actor1FirstName": "Craig T",
            "actor1LastName": "Nelson"
            },
            {
            "actor2FirstName": "Holly",
            "actor2LastName": "Hunter"
            }
        ],
        "directorFirstName": "Brad",
        "directorLastName": "Bird",
        "genre": ["Adventure","Action","Animation"], 
        "keyword": ["Elastigirl","Dash","Jack Jack"]
    }
]
);
db.RentalCollection.insertMany(
[
    {
        "_id": "0000010", 
        "userID": "PB0000002", 
        "userFirstName" : "Kolten", 
        "userLastName": "Nay", 
        "userPhoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "userType": "A", 
        "customerType": "P", 
        "banStatus": "N", 
        "password": "SQLRules", 
        "question": 
        [
            {
            "Question1": "Who is the best professor in the CS Department?",
            "Answer1": "Cody Squadroni"
            },
            {
            "Question2": "What was the name of your first pet?",
            "Answer2": "Kirby"
            }
        ],
        "rentalDate": "Aug 1 2020", 
        "returnDate": "null", 
        "dueDate": "Aug 4 2020", 
        "copyNumber": "1", 
        "movieType": "D", 
        "title": "Deadpool", 
        "actor":
        [
            {
            "actor1FirstName": "Ryan",
            "actor1LastName": "Reynolds"
            },
            {
            "actor2FirstName": "Morena",
            "actor2LastName": "Baccarin"
            }
        ],
        "directorFirstName": "Tim",
        "directorLastName": "Miller",
        "genre": ["Adventure","Action","Comedy"], 
        "keyword": ["Mercinary","Morbid","Healing Power"]
    },
    {
        "_id": "0000011", 
        "userID": "PB0000002", 
        "userFirstName" : "Kolten", 
        "userLastName": "Nay", 
        "userPhoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "userType": "A", 
        "customerType": "P", 
        "banStatus": "N", 
        "password": "SQLRules", 
        "question": 
        [
            {
            "Question1": "Who is the best professor in the CS Department?",
            "Answer1": "Cody Squadroni"
            },
            {
            "Question2": "What was the name of your first pet?",
            "Answer2": "Kirby"
            }
        ],
        "rentalDate": "Aug 1 2020", 
        "returnDate": "null", 
        "dueDate": "Aug 4 2020",
        "copyNumber": "1", 
        "movieType": "D", 
        "title": "Incredibles 2", 
        "actor":
        [
            {
            "actor1FirstName": "Craig T",
            "actor1LastName": "Nelson"
            },
            {
            "actor2FirstName": "Holly",
            "actor2LastName": "Hunter"
            }
        ],
        "directorFirstName": "Brad",
        "directorLastName": "Bird",
        "genre": ["Adventure","Action","Animation"], 
        "keyword": ["Elastigirl","Dash","Jack Jack"]
    },
    {
        "_id": "0000012", 
        "userID": "PB0000002", 
        "userFirstName" : "Kolten", 
        "userLastName": "Nay", 
        "userPhoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "userType": "A", 
        "customerType": "P", 
        "banStatus": "N", 
        "password": "SQLRules", 
        "question": 
        [
            {
            "Question1": "Who is the best professor in the CS Department?",
            "Answer1": "Cody Squadroni"
            },
            {
            "Question2": "What was the name of your first pet?",
            "Answer2": "Kirby"
            }
        ],
        "rentalDate": "Aug 1 2020", 
        "returnDate": "null", 
        "dueDate": "Aug 4 2020", 
        "copyNumber": "1", 
        "movieType": "D", 
        "title": "X-Men", 
        "actor":
        [
            {
            "actor1FirstName": "Hugh",
            "actor1LastName": "Jackman"
            },
            {
            "actor2FirstName": "Patrick",
            "actor2LastName": "Stewart"
            }
        ],
        "directorFirstName": "Bryan",
        "directorLastName": "Singer",
        "genre": ["Adventure","Action","Sci-Fi"], 
        "keyword": ["Wolverine","Mutants"]
    },
]
);
db.RentalCollection.find();
db.RentalCollection.updateOne(
{ _id: "0000001"},
{ $set: { returnDate: "Jul 01 2020"}}
);
db.RentalCollection.updateOne(
{ _id: "0000002"},
{ $set: { returnDate: "Jul 01 2020"}}
);
db.RentalCollection.updateOne(
{ _id: "0000003"},
{ $set: { returnDate: "Jul 01 2020"}}
);
db.RentalCollection.updateOne(
{ _id: "0000004"},
{ $set: { returnDate: "Jul 01 2020"}}
);
db.RentalCollection.updateOne(
{ _id: "0000005"},
{ $set: { returnDate: "Jul 01 2020"}}
);
db.RentalCollection.updateOne(
{ _id: "0000006"},
{ $set: { returnDate: "Jul 01 2020"}}
);
db.RentalCollection.updateOne(
{ _id: "0000007"},
{ $set: { returnDate: "Jul 01 2020"}}
);
db.RentalCollection.updateOne(
{ _id: "0000008"},
{ $set: { returnDate: "Jul 01 2020"}}
);
db.RentalCollection.updateOne(
{ _id: "0000009"},
{ $set: { returnDate: "Jul 01 2020"}}
);
db.RentalCollection.updateOne(
{ _id: "0000010"},
{ $set: { returnDate: "Aug 02 2020"}}
);
db.RentalCollection.updateOne(
{ _id: "0000011"},
{ $set: { returnDate: "Aug 02 2020"}}
);
db.RentalCollection.updateOne(
{ _id: "0000012"},
{ $set: { returnDate: "Aug 02 2020"}}
);
db.RentalCollection.aggregate(
{ $project: {_id: 0, userFirstName: 1, userLastName: 1, title: 1, rentalDate: 1, actor1FirstName: 1, actor1LastName: 1,actor2FirstName: 1, actor2LastName: 1, directorFirstName: 1, directorLastName: 1, movieType: 1 }}
);
```

full error from terminal:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("775add23-e465-4fe3-a32f-f0ac8a4753cc") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.8
2020-08-02T10:54:36.056-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:8
2020-08-02T10:54:36.056-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:11
2020-08-02T10:54:36.057-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:8
2020-08-02T10:54:36.057-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:7
2020-08-02T10:54:36.059-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal :
@(shell):1:8
2020-08-02T10:54:36.059-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '-' :
@(shell):1:2
2020-08-02T10:54:36.059-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:8
2020-08-02T10:54:36.060-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:4
2020-08-02T10:54:36.060-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:13
2020-08-02T10:54:36.061-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:3
2020-08-02T10:54:36.061-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '-' :
@(shell):1:2
2020-08-02T10:54:36.061-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal :
@(shell):1:8
2020-08-02T10:54:36.062-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '>' :
@(shell):1:0
bye
```

Comment: At what line are you getting this error? Can you paste the entire error?

Comment: @Gibbs I've edited to include the entire error.  Thanks for your time :)